# Carrierwave - destruir objeto só depois dele ter sido deletado do meu armazenamento

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Carrierwave só deleta o arquivo 'montado' depois do objeto no banco de dados ter sido removido:

```
after_commit :remove_avatar! :on => :destroy
```

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

Estou implementando um concern de BackgroundDestroyable e para isso tenho um worker que deleta os arquivos.

O campo `deleted_at` registra quando o objeto foi marcado para remoção completa e para garantir que os objetos só sejam removidos de fato pelo worker eu precisei redefinir o `destroy` no concern.

Se um dos workers recebe um timeout eu perco a referência dos meus arquivos orfãos no S3, já que meus objetos no banco de dados foram deletados.

O que eu devo fazer pra garantir que não ficarei com orfãos no S3?
Chamar `remove_avatar!` direto antes do `object.destroy` e depois fazer um `skip_callback?`

É seguro fazer isso?

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi a parte do Timeout, o que recebe Timeout? O seu script ou a Amazon?

Comment: @Ricardo meu script (no caso meu worker rails) é quem recebe o timeout. Por algum motivo ele pode não conseguir se comunicar com o S3 enquanto procede com as exclusões dos arquivos e daí acontece o problema dos orfãos.

Comment: `before_destroy :remove_avatar!` ??

Comment: Meu problema é que eu estava fazendo um Concern para soft delete (BackgroundDestroyable) e a lógica ficava um pouco mais complexa (eu estava redefinindo o destroy e remover o arquivo no before_destroy não funcionaria).

De qualquer maneira acho que não tem problema em chamar o `before_destroy :remove_avatar!` mesmo que o carrierwave vá chamar o método novamente depois do commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que fiz foi chamar o `remove_avatar!` antes de chamar `super()` e fazer a remoção de fato, sem mudar nada nos callbacks.

Para registro, segue o código do concern:

```
# BackgroundDestroyable classes MUST have deleted_at:datetime column
module BackgroundDestroyable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    default_scope { where(deleted_at: nil) }
    scope :deleted, -> { unscoped.where.not(deleted_at: nil) }
  end

  def destroy(mode = :background)
    if mode == :background
      unless self.deleted_at.present?
        update_attribute :deleted_at, Time.now
        Resque.enqueue(BackgroundDestroyer, self.id, self.class.to_s)
      end
    elsif mode == :now
      self.class.uploaders.each do |uploader, uploader_class|
        self.send("remove_#{uploader}!")
      end
      super()
    end
  end

  def destroy_now!
    self.destroy(:now)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Pra mim, faz mais sentido chamar `remove_avatar!` antes de chamar o `object.destroy`. Assim, você sempre tem como garantir que não terá objetos órfãos no S3, verificando se o objeto foi removido de fato.

Prefiro não mexer nos callbacks, exceto se eu souber exatamente o que estiver fazendo. Além disso, sempre prefiro deixar o comportamento explícito no código e callbacks não são muito explicitos. E, por experiência própria, você vai se agradecer muito daqui a alguns meses quando precisar olhar esse script e fazer alguma manutenção nele.

Comment: Mas para fazer um remove_avatar! antes do object.destroy sem usar callback pode ser problemático, já que meu destroy tem algumas condições dentro do modelo (por exemplo, só deletar um objeto quando ele não tiver nenhum filho [mais ou menos como a amazon faz com os buckets dela, que você só pode deletar se estiverem vazios])

Comment: Então vejo como viável, você separar todos esses testes pré-destroy em um outro método, chamar esse método, depois chamar o `remove_avatar!` e por fim o `object.destroy`. Vejo, dessa forma que cada método é responsável apenas por uma pequena responsabilidade, ao invés de ter um grande método que faz tudo e é difícil de dar manutenção.